# Firefox redirects to the a[href] value when clicking in a input[type=checkbox] inside that a. preventDefault disable selection?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have a `<a href="...">` that contains a `<input type="checkbox">` and put a click event listener on the link, if the user clicks on the checkbox on Firefox, they get redirected.

If I put a `preventDefault`, they aren't redirected BUT the checkbox is not changed anymore.

This is not the case on Chrome and Edge.

Here's a reproducible code :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      selecteds: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick($event) {
      if ($event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        $event.stopImmediatePropagation()
      }
      console.log($event.target)
      console.log('clicekd')
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <a href="https://google.com" @click="onClick($event)">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="selecteds" :value="item" @change /> {{ item }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I toggle the checkbox on click without redirecting to the link on the href?

Update: It seems to be an issue with Firefox? https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12490

Comment: Can you please share your codepen or any other remote link ?

Comment: If you click on "Run code snippet", you'll be able to have the demo version.

Comment: It's a really old bug. The duplicate is over 10 years old.

Comment: And the Firefox Bugzilla is 22 years old!

Comment: Rendering checkboxes inside anchors will lose you (or your client) users (therefore money) very fast (statistically speaking). It's a UX nightmare, especially when considering accessibility. It's difficult to describe how bad it is. Leaving that aside, what you need to do to achieve what you want (technically) is `pointer-events: none` on the anchors. A separate problem is you don't currently have `<label>`s. So the text doesn't act as a label for the checkbox. You might want to wrap your `<input/>` + text into `<label/>`s.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5L9xd21e/)

Comment: Thank you @tao, I run the demo on Firefox, but still got redirected after clicking on it. The debate seems to be that it's not ideal in term of accessibility. The fact that this bug is known for 10 years old seems to indicate this won't change soon !

Comment: @Cyril, you were right. On FF, the link was still functional when clicking on the `<input>`, but not when clicking outside of it (on `<label>`). I've updated the demo by additionally applying `pointer-events: none` to `.checkbox-label input`. It now seems to work as expected, even on Firefox, at least on v102.0.1. Cheers!

Comment: I have filed a [separate bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1778700) on bugzilla. The previous bug was closed as "intended behaviour", on par with the HTML spec. And, in fairness, it is. Pointer events do bubble. When a pointer event bubbles up from an input to an anchor parent, the anchor should behave exactly as if the pointer event came from any other descendant. The bug I filed is a proper bug. `pointer-events: none` should never be ignored on anchor elements. On any elements, for that matter.